# Django unit upload zipfile

Tags: python, django, forms, unit-testing, upload

For my project made in Django, I have a page with a form allowing the user to upload a zipfile.
Then from this zip file, I open it and read a file from there.
I started with the unit tests to validate all cases :
- Not a .zip extension
- `zipfile.is_zipfile()` return False
- Can't find the file I want to read inside
- File inside is invalid

For my unit tests, I create different files for each error, and upload it using `django.test.Client` as so :

```
with open_file('wrong_format.zip') as file:
            response = self.client.post(url, {'archive': file})
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
            self.assertContains(response, '<li>Only zip archived are allowed</li>')
```

But I get the following error : `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 10: invalid start byte`

It works fine when I do it from the browser.

Here's the stack :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/plugins/tests/uploads.py", line 33, in test_bad_archive
    response = self.client.post(url, {'archive': file})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 548, in post
    secure=secure, **extra)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 347, in post
    post_data = self._encode_data(data, content_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 311, in _encode_data
    return encode_multipart(BOUNDARY, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 201, in encode_multipart
    lines.extend(encode_file(boundary, key, value))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 254, in encode_file
    to_bytes(file.read())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 10: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Could you post the stack trace? It would help to see which function internal is having this issue.

Comment: Yes, I just edit it

Comment: What is `open_file()`? Why not regular `open()`? Also I think the issue is that you're not opening the file in binary mode (`open('file.zip', 'rb')`).

Comment: `open_file()` was a wrapper for `open()` that prepend the directory. opening it in binary mode fixed it, thanks !

Comment: I posted an answer, please accept it so this question doesn't show up as unanswered in the search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening the file without the binary flag `b` was ok in Python 2 where binary and string were the same datatype, but Python 3 is more strict about it. So if you do `open(file, 'rb')` the system won't try to interpret the zip file as text.